# How to merge all 3-grams into smallest possible string?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, strings

There is a set of all possible letters: $A = \{ a, b, \ldots, z \}.$
Then the set of all possible 3-grams looks like that:
$A^3 = A \times A \times A = $
$\{$
$\;\;(a, a, a), $
$\;\;(a, a, b), $
$\;\;(a, a, c), $
$\;\;\;\; \ldots, $
$\;\;(a, a, z), $
$\;\;(b, a, a), $
$\;\;\;\; \ldots, $
$\;\;(z, z, y), $
$\;\;(z, z, z), $
$\}$

$|A^3| = 26^3 = 17576$

- If we try to merge $aaa$ with $bbb$ we have to append $bbb$ to the end of $aaa$, because they don't *overlap*:
  merge($aaa$, $bbb$) = $aaabbb$
- If we merge $aaa$ with $aab$ we can create a smaller string of length 4:
  merge($aaa$, $aab$) = $aaab$

In the best case, if we manage to always do a second kind of merge, we will be extending the resulting string by 1 character. There are $17576$ triplets, so there can be at most $17575$ single character extensions. This will result in $17575 + 3 = 17578$ characters string.

In the worst case, we will append all of the 3-grams to each other, thus creating a $17576 * 3 = 52728$ characters string.

**How to combine all of them to get the total string of the minimum length?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "merge"? If it comes close to [multiple sequence alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment#Multiple_sequence_alignment), this may be NP-hard (in general). But then, you are asking for a solution for a *fixed* instance; so what do you want an algorithm for, anyway?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  1. Are you asking for the minimum-length string $S$ such that every 3-gram appears somewhere (consecutively) as a substring of $S$?  If so, it would help to state that explicitly in your post.  2. What have you tried so far?  What are your thoughts?  What's the best solution you've found to date?  What concepts have you learned recently in your class that might be relevant?  We're happy to help you learn concepts, but just solving exercise-style problems for you is unlikely to achieve that.

Comment: I am not a student. This is a problem I came up with after solving a similar problem. I've asked that question on [codeforces](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/48808?locale=en) and Alexandr Lyashko pointed me to a De Bruijn sequence. At first I also thought that it is some kind of NP-[complete|hard] problem and tried to google it, but as it turned out it has a simple algorithm which is even used in CRC codes.